# How to Find disk capacity of node alpine Docker image?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

How would find the specific disk space capacity of a node:14-alpine3.14 docker image?  I have read that docker didn't used to allow you to set image disk size limitations, but more recent posts say it can be specified using something like :

`docker run -it --storage-opt size=120G fedora /bin/bash`

That is fine, but if I have an image, how can I look into the docker image and find out what the size limitations (if any) it is set to?

Comment: That question doesn't make sense; an image doesn't have a "disk" or "capacity".  It's like asking "what is the disk size of `/bin/ls`?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is the mounted filesystem with the required depencies for the application to run. The only limitation you might encounter is the host machine disk size limit or inode count limit, there are no inherited limitation on the image, there are limitations on the container (the image instance) if you set any at runtime like with the example you've added.

Comment: thanks, I realize now the way I worded the question wasn't accurate to the context. Thanks for clarifying via the concise answer.